# How do I drop a column and create a new one instead of renaming in EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

Trying to delete two columns and add a new column (no relationship between deleted and new) in one of my models but the generated migration renames one of the deleted column instead. Since the deleted columns hold data in production, they must be dropped instead of renamed.

Is there a way to fix this so the generated migration drops and create instead of renaming?

**Variables in model:**

```
public DateTime? PublishedAt { get; private set; }
public bool? IsValidated { get; private set; }
public States? States { get; private set; } // Added
public Invites? Invites { get; private set; } // Removed
public string Info { get; private set; } // Removed
```

**Generated migration:**

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
        name: "Info",
        table: "Articles");

    migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(
        name: "Invites",
        table: "Articles",
        newName: "States");
}
```

Comment: One way to solve this is to make the model changes in two stages so that you become two migrations. One migration for deleting the columns and another migration to add the new field. You could also manipulate the migration manually so that it drops the two colums and adds a new one. If you choose for the latter approach, it's best to make the inverted change in the Down() method as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes EF can think you want to rename a column, as opposed to creating a column if the types are the same.

It's not an exact science so either create a migration to first delete the column, apply, then create another to add a new one so EF picks up on them as separate operations, or I would just change the migration manually.

In case of the latter option, use the [`MigrationBuilder.AddColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.addcolumn?view=efcore-5.0) method to add the `States` column & then change `RenameColumn` to `DropColumn` and drop `Invites`:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
        name: "Info",
        table: "Articles");

    migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
        name: "Invites",
        table: "Articles");

    migrationBuilder.AddColumn(
        name: "States",
        table: "Articles");
}
```

In case you ever want to revert the migration, remember to also change the `Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)` method so that it carries out the reverse of your updated `Up(...)` method, not the old one:

```
protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn(
        name: "Info",
        table: "Articles");

    migrationBuilder.AddColumn(
        name: "Invites",
        table: "Articles");

    migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
        name: "States",
        table: "Articles");
}
```